# CGContext line indented

Tags: ios, iphone, graphics, line, cgcontext

So, I'm drawing a line on iOS but the result is a little indented:

[image: Line]

Actually I'm dealing with the context in this way:

```
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.25);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
CGContextSetMiterLimit(context, 0.25);
```

I close the path and rendering the context as UIImage. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the part of code which sets up the context.

Comment: http://imgur.com/XVNgjvp :)